# Android Studio Colours Not Working

Tags: android, colors, styles, toolbar

I have no idea what happened but all of a sudden - after making no changes to any files - the colours of my app stopped working incorrectly - the toolbar colour isnt working, neither is the white background - everything is just grey.

Here is my color file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <color name="colourPrimary">#e91e63</color>
        <color name="colourPrimaryDark">#C2185B</color>
        <color name="colourAccent">#89ff00</color>
        <color name="colourNavIcon">#808080</color>
    </resources>

Here is my styles file:
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colourPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colourPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colourAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="primary_style" parent = "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:layout_height">48dp</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/colourPrimary</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And here is my v21/styles file:

```
<resources>>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colourPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colourPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colourAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Everything was working fine on Marshmallow, so I tried it on kitkat and discovered that the toolbar colour was missing, so I then tried marshmallow again and it just disappeared - as I said I made no changes.
Also I don't know if it means anything, but I can't see the 'attr' file - I never have been able to, but that might be helpful to know - I'd also like to know how to be able to see it if anyone knows?

Also the colour is present in the editor viewport.

Comment: This sentence is making confusion `Everything was working fine on Marshmallow, so I tried it on kitkat and discovered that the toolbar colour was missing, so I then tried marshmallow again and it just disappeared`

Comment: When I tried it on Marshmallow again after trying it on KitKat the toolbar ccolour disappeared - sorry for any confusion